# LinearRegressionWithSGD doesn't converge on file of more than 11Mb

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 along with scala 2.11.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04 with following memory settings for my project: `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8G -Xms2G"`.

My data is organized in 20 json-like files, every file is about 8-15 Mb, containing categorical and numerical values. I parse this data, passing by DataFrame facilities and then scale one numerical feature and create dummy variables for categorical features.

So far from initial 14 keys of my json-like file I get about 200-240 features in the final LabeledPoint. The final data is sparse and every file contains about 20000-30000 of observations.

I try to run two types of algorithms on data : `LinearRegressionWithSGD` or `LassoWithSGD`, since the data is sparse and regularization might be required.

For data larger than 11MB  LinearRegressionWithSGD fails with the following error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 58 in stage 346.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 58.0 in stage 346.0 (TID 18140, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 179307 ms.

I faced the same problem with the file of 11Mb (for file of 5MB algorithm works well), and after trying a lot of debug options (testing different options for driver.memory & executors.memory, making sure that cache is cleared properly, proper use of `coalesce()`), I've found out that setting up the `StepSize` of `Gradientt Descent` to `1` resolves this bug (while for 5MB file-size `StepSize = 0.4` doesn't bug and gives the better results).

So I tried to augment the StepSize for file-size of 12MB (setting up of StepSize to 1.5 and 2) but it didn't work. If I take only 10 Mb of file instead of whole file, the algorithm doesn't fail.

It's very embarrassing since I need construct the model on whole file, that seems to be still far from Big Data formats.

If I can not run Linear Regression on 12 Mb, could I run it on larger sets? I notices that while using StandardScaler on preprocessing step and counts on Linear Regression step, `collect()` method is perform, that can cause the bug. So the possibility to scale Linear regression is questioned, cause, as I far as I understand it, collect() performs on driver and so the sens of scaled calculations is lost.

The following parameters are set:

```
val algorithme = new LinearRegressionWithSGD() //LassoWithSGD()
algorithme.setIntercept(true)
algorithme.optimizer
  .setNumIterations(100)
  .setStepSize(1)
```

Comment: can you see (in the spark UI) which stage failed exactly? the collect() is probably done on a small portion of the data (preferably constant in size) so I wouldn't worry about scaling up, this is the entire idea of spark

Comment: @z-star It fails on the stage `treeAggregate at GradientDescent.scala` . as I can see from theSpark UI . This stage, as well as every collect has 200 tasks, and it gives me idea, that multiple `collect()` operations might shut down Spark and cause the failure, because LinearRegressionWithSGD uses multiple `treeAgregate` stages on given LabeledPoint of 240 features and 30000 rows.